# Чтение из бинарного файла

Tags: c, файлы

При чтении из бинарного файла (!feof) считывает последние значение 2 раза.

Запись в бинарный файл

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  FILE *f = fopen("file.dat", "w+b");
  int a;
  scanf("%i",&a);
  while (a != -1)
  {
    fwrite(&a, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    scanf("%i",&a);
  }
  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

Чтение из файла и вывод на экран

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   FILE *f = fopen("file.dat","rb");
   int a;
   while(!feof(f))
   {
     fread(&a,sizeof(int),1,f);
     printf("%d ", a);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Пример:
Ввод
1 2 3 4 -1
Вывод
1 2 3 4 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(fread(&a,sizeof(int),1,f)==1)
{
     printf("%d ", a);
}
```

EOF выставляется **после неудачного чтения**

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Answer (score 1):

Проверку на EOF надо делать после вызова `fread()` и перед `printf()`.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)